# Is there an universal (dis)similarity measure between two structures?

Tags: graph-theory, it.information-theory, mathematical-philosophy, similarity

I'm always wondering is there an universal (dis)similarity measure
between two structures (let's say between two undirected simple
graphs)?  I mean, not "the measure with universal parameter that we
can adapt to our needs", but rather "a measure without any parameters,
magical, a measure that reads our mind(s)".

The [normalized compression
distance(NCD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_compression_distance)
seems to be a good candidate for such universal measure. But it have
at least two problems:

1. NCD is *just* an approximation of [the information distance
   (ID)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_distance). Although
   it should be noted that ID cannot be computed at all.
2. NCD (and ID) compares not the objects themselves, but their
   representations – we must transform our objects to strings.  And
   sometimes this transformation, $\text{Object} ↦ \text{String}$, can
   be very tricky, for example:

   *Take two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$.  Of course, we can take their
   adjacency matrices: $A_1$ and $A_2$; and NCD will tell us how these
   matrices are similar. But isomorphic graphs can have very different
   adjacency matrices... Therefore, if we want to capture the graph
   isomorphism by NCD, we must use canonical labeling instead
   of adjacency matrices.*

So, how can we develop an universal (dis)similarity measure between
two structures? How can such a measure guess the most
natural\universal isomorphism between them?

Comment: a universal distance measure will be uncomputable....(it seems also a somewhat philosophical issue: whether we really compare objects or their representations, because true representations themselves are nothing but objects isomorphic to the original objects....?)